# Number of Paths in a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have an undirected, unweighted graph. Let us fix a vertex and find all distinct paths from that vertex which covers all vertices of the graph. The task is to find the number of possible such paths from every vertices. 
 Eg: Let us take a graph of **4 vertices** `[ 1, 2, 3, 4]`. And the **edges** are (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2). Here **answer** is **4**. The paths are `1>2>3>4`, `1>2>4>3`, `3>4>2>1`, `4>3>2>1`.

---

I have come with an algorithm which uses brute-force technique to find the number of possible such paths, initialized by each vertex.
Eg:
For the above example: 
`From vertex 1 there is 2 such path;` 
`From vertex 2 there is no such path;` 
`From vertex 3 there is 1 such path;` 
`From vertex 4 there is 1 such path;` 
So the **answer** is **2+1+1=4**.

---

Is it possible to solve this problem in a better *time complexity?*

Comment: What is time complexity of your brute force algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an O(2^n n^2)-time algorithm obtained by modifying the [Held--Karp DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Dynamic_programming_approach). The idea is, for each subset S of vertices paired with some endpoint t in S, compute the number of paths that visit exactly the vertices in S and end at t by summing, for each neighbor u of t that is in S, the count for visiting S - {t} and ending at u. As a base case, the singleton sets all have count 1. In Python 3:

```
import itertools
def count_hamilton_paths(graph):  # graph is a dict of adjacency lists
    vertices = frozenset(graph)
    table = {(frozenset({t}), t): 1 for t in vertices}
    for r in range(2, len(vertices) + 1):
        for subset_tuple in itertools.combinations(vertices, r):
            subset = frozenset(subset_tuple)
            for t in subset:
                subset_minus_t = subset - frozenset({t})
                table[(subset, t)] = sum(table[(subset_minus_t, u)]
                                         for u in graph[t]
                                         if u in subset_minus_t)
    return sum(table[(vertices, t)] for t in vertices)

print(count_hamilton_paths({1: {2}, 2: {1, 3, 4}, 3: {2, 4}, 4: {2, 3}}))
```